# relation between cross compilation tools and OS

Tags: compiler-construction, embedded, operating-system, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

HI, All,

I have a question regarding the cross compilation tools (compiler, assemble, linker, etc.) and operating system. let's take ELDK  and linux kernel as an example.

From the wiki and the ibm tutorial (https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/l-cross/l-cross-ltr.pdf), the configured cross compiler should be aware of some certain target OS header files as well as new libc, etc. However, the target OS kernel also will be cross compiled via the cross compiler, e.g., eldk, on the target embedded board or machine.

So who comes first? OS or the cross compiler?

Thanks for any clarifications!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very first version of any OS must either be cross-compiled, or (for a very simple OS, as in the olden days) hand-written in machine code. More complex executables can then be targeted at the simpler OS, and possibly used to build a more complex OS (the initial compile is called "bootstrapping", the process of an OS compiling itself is called "self-hosting".) Some OSs become self-hosting, some never do, if they're not designed for that level of complexity.

In any case, I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. Many small-device OSs aren't designed to handle a file system and the other complexities needed to host a compiler, so they never become capable of compiling their own code, and cross-compilation is always necessary. The libraries used by a cross-compiler may well have themselves been cross-compiled; the headers are always those of the target system, too, of course.

Comment: hi, Ernest, thanks for your answer. I did not understand from your description. If you like, by reading the IBM how to build a cross compiler, you will notice the cross compiler requires its target OS header files and libraries. However, as we all know that if you have a kernel source, etc, you need to make it cross compiled via something, which requires a cross compiler. it sounds to me like a chicken egg relation. So I suspect I should misunderstand something here.

Comment: It *is* a chicken-egg problem. The very first bit of code you compile (or assemble) for a new platform has to be compiled without any special supporting files at all: there are no special headers, no libraries for that system at all. Therefore that very first version is going to be very simple, and a lot of work will be done by hand. For example, the very first bit might be code to read a program over a serial port and execute it. That program would need to be written by hand, at least partially in assembler.

Comment: But now there's a library function that talks to the serial port, and you can keep a copy of it on the host system, and use it in your next program: it's the first "library". Perhaps the next program would be some rudimentary disk I/O, so you could save files on the new system. These routines would also have to be coded in machine language, mostly by hand. Third, you might do simple I/O routines.

Comment: But then, you have everything you need to create a very simple compiler. Now your host system can compile a simple compiler onto the new system, calling those I/O routines as needed. And so you don't have to write in assembly any more, and in fact, you're close to getting the new system to self-host.

Comment: thank you Ernest, your answer really helps. btw, is there some related material or document around to describe this in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Neither the kernel nor the user-space cross-compiler come first.

Typically, you don't compile the OS kernel with the same cross-compiler you use for userspace.  Instead, you compile the kernel and C library with a "bootstrap" cross-compiler that's intended for compiling things to run directly on the hardware without help from an OS, and which is set up to not look for a pre-existing libc.  At that point, you have your kernel and core libraries, and can use those to create the normal userspace cross-compiler.

(Linux is somewhat of an exception to this on the kernel side, as there's a fair bit of hackery included that makes it possible to use a userspace compiler to compile the Linux kernel.  It's not at all a good example of "normal".  But even there the cross-compiler comes first; you don't need to compile the kernel to be able to include kernel header files.)